# AngularJS run tests

Tags: angularjs, npm, jasmine

I have project with Symfony2 and AngularJS and I want to use Jasmine to test Frontend.

Angular files are in `web/js`.

I know I can use `npm` to sun tests with command `npm test`, but i this case I have to have `package.json` file in my main directory of project.

I'm not sure I should use `npm` to run tests. Maybe I should run this in other way - just run `Jasmine` without `npm`.

Comment: I would recommend looking into a task runner, such as Gulp or Grunt. I use gulp personally, combined with the [gulp-jasmine](https://www.npmjs.com/package/gulp-jasmine) plugin. Then these tests just become a part of your overall build process.